# SOAP maximum request size exceding server limit

Tags: soap, java-me, request

I have a set of IIS7 hosted SOAP web services (MSSOAP 3.0) that are being consumed by a .Net web application as well as by a J2ME application (currently running through an emulator). The web application can successfully call all of the defined methods. The J2ME application succesfully calls all of the methods except for those that POST data bigger than 2K. The failing methods return the following error:

```
The size of the request exceeds the limit allowed by the server
```

The amount of data being sent through for this call is not large. It is less than that submitted by the web application and it is also well below the limit defined in the registry setting (currently 102400):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE / SOFTWARE / Microsoft / MSSOAP / 30 / SOAPISAP / MaxPostSize
```

Does anyone have an idea why the J2ME application would fail with this error.

**UPDATE**

When POSTing data from the J2ME application the Http connection class inserts "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" into the request header when the message size is bigger than ~2K. This will replace any "Content-Length" that may have also been added to the header. The HttpConnection class does not allow this behaviour to be overridden.

If I simulate the method call using telnet with the same data from the J2ME application then the call goes through successfully.

After analyzing the packets sent from the J2ME application and the telnet simulation I noted that the telnet approach did not include the chunking header. The packets from the J2ME application were incomplete. Only the headers and the last packet were sent possibly due to the way IIS is handling the request. IIS7 has chunking enabled.

I have found similar reports of this problem else where on the internet but no solution. The following link describes a problem similar to mine.

[Thread: j2me http post problem in IIS 6.0](http://forums.iis.net/t/1123960.aspx)